# Bluetooth no longer connecting to device after update

Tags: bluetooth

After a recent update, i am no longer able to connect to a pair of bluetooth headphones. This is both from the GUI applet and CLI using `bluetoothctl`. I have removed the device and tried to repair to no avail. after some digging i noticed i also no longer have `pavucontrol` installed anymore, and i need to reinstall `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`.

I try re-installing `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` and i get this:

```
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4) but 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.5 is to be installed
                                  Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4)

   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, i should just try to downgrade `libpulse0` right?

Well, when i try to do `sudo apt install libpulse0=1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4` i get this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   blueman elementary-desktop gala gnome-settings-daemon libcanberra-pulse libpulse-mainloop
glib0 libpulsedsp pantheon-shell
  pantheon-xsession-settings pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils switchboard-plug-notifications switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell
  switchboard-plug-sound wingpanel-indicator-sound

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libpulse0

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 15 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 265 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I should **NOT** do this right?

But how can i get my bluetooth headphones connected again?

How did this happen?

Does this have anything to do with pipewire?